# Is there a migration path to call maven plugin in bazel?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, bazel

I'm trying to convert a maven project to bazel projet. Everything works well by following the tutorials of bazel website. However, there is a project that use `antlr4-maven-plugin` to generate java code automatically. So I wonder if there is a feasible way to call maven plugin in bazel?

Comment: I would think it does not ...cause Bazel does not contain the appropriate context to run a maven-plugin ...

Comment: I just found an Antlr plugin at https://github.com/marcohu/rules_antlr#antlr4.

Comment: The Antlr plugins is explicitly implemented for Bazel..so it's not using a Maven plugin...